# CSS not working for div with text

Tags: css, html, hover

I have a row of divs with :hover and it is working when I hover over the images within the divs. However, it doesn't want to work for the text. I am on the newer side of html and css, so help appreciated. I must be missing something obvious?

The first one with the div.topIconsHover:hover CSS works. The other does not. I have tried applying the topIconsHover class to the div as well and it still doesn't work. So, I must be doing something wrong with the HTML? But I'm just not sure what. Help appreciated! Thanks.

Note: I have the CSS in an external sheet.

```
div.topIconsHover:hover {
    background-color:#555555;
}

<div class="topIcons topIconsHover">            
    <a href="tools.html"><img src="tools16lg.png" /></a>                
</div>

div.topTextHover:hover {
    background-color:#555555;
    color:#ffffff
}

<div id="topBrowse" class="topTextHover">       
    <a href="browse.html">Browse</a>                    
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color attribute is working only with text elements, not divs. So you should apply the class tag to your href tag like this :

```
<style type="text/css">
.topTextHover:hover {
    background-color:#555555;
    color:#ffffff
}
</style>

<div id="topBrowse">       
    <a href="browse.html" class="topTextHover">Browse</a>                    
</div>
```

EDIT :

If you're looking to define a base class for the link itself, and a HOVER state, do it like this :

```
<style type="text/css">
.topTextHover {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #0000ff;
}
.topTextHover:hover {
    background-color: #555555;
    color: #ffffff;
}
</style>

<div id="topBrowse">       
    <a href="browse.html" class="topTextHover">Browse</a>                    
</div>
```

Good luck

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work. Also, even the background-color doesn't work.

Comment: TIP: "div.theStyle" indicate the style will only apply to divs, "a.theStyle" indicate the style will only apply on anchor tags. If you don't specify the element type like I did (.theStyle, no div. or no a.), the style can be applied to different elements.

Comment: I know this code doesn't work in Lynx Viewer.. ;-) Remember to replace "div.topTextHover:hover" by ".topTextHover:hover" in your code.

Comment: This doesn't do what I believe the OP wants, the text will only become white when the text itself is hovered over, not when simply hovering over the div. You still get a barely readable blue on dark gray effect.

Comment: I appreciate the tip about removing the "div." or "a." to make it more generic. That's good to know. Anyway after removing that and applying the "class=" within <a>... the background finally worked at least. The background also works if my mouse hovers anyway within the div. However, the text still does not change color (not even when it's directly rolled over).

Answer (score 1):

Anchor tags have a default text colour which gets priority (usually blue). What you need is to define this explicitly:

```
div.topIconsHover:hover {
    background-color: #555555;
}

div.topTextHover:hover {
    background-color: #555555;
}

div.topTextHover:hover a {
    color: #ffffff
}
```

Comment: It still won't work. I separated the classes like you did and the changing text color still doesn't work. I even tried taking that out entirely and just getting the background to work... but I hover my mouse and get nothing.

Comment: You shouldn't need all of those pseudo classes, but I just want to make sure it's not a cross-browser issue or because I haven't actually visited the link myself (really it's probably just the visited pseudo class causing the problem).

Comment: I tried the update (even with all the :link, :visited, etc.) ... and it still doesn't seem to work. Hmmm...

Comment: @user1066982: Check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7s9zW/1/. This is your code. If this works, take a second look at your code to make sure you have no syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

You applied style to the ":hover text" but not for links. This should do the trick (not tested):

```
div.topIconsHover:hover {
    background-color:#555555;
}

<div class="topIcons topIconsHover">            
    <a href="tools.html"><img src="tools16lg.png" /></a>                
</div>

div.topTextHover:hover, div.topTextHover:hover a {
    background-color:#555555;
    color:#ffffff
}

<div id="topBrowse" class="topTextHover">       
    <a href="browse.html">Browse</a>                    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two really simple ways to resolve this issue.

First if you don't have any height/width requirements on the anchor tag (`<a href=''></a>`) being inside the div do the following:

```
.topTextHover a:hover{
    background-color:#555555;
    color:#ffffff
}

<div id="topBrowse" class="topTextHover">       
    <a href="browse.html">Browse</a>                    
</div>
```

If you do have spacial requirements for the text inside the div (i.e. you want the text to be vertically-aligned to the center and horizontally centered) then I would do the following note* this is backwards compatible but is really only compliant with CSS3

```
#BrowseLink:hover {
    background-color:#555555;
    color:#ffffff
}

<a id="BrowseLink" href="browse.html">
  <div id="topBrowse" class="topTextHover">       
    Browse                   
  </div>
</a>
```

Also of note IE6 doesn't like the pseudo-class hover on anything other than an anchor tag and therefor will not work properly.  This may be applicable in other browsers as well but the main one that I know that has issues is IE6 of the browsers that are typically seen on a website.